# A Couple of Questions from a Newbie

Tags: settings, mailchimp, opt-out

I apologize ahead of time, I was brought on to fix a company's website, but they asked me to do their CiviCRM. Instead, I've never done this, nor have I ever heard of it before this.

They have a few concerns, and I was hoping you guys could help me. No, I'm not getting paid, I'm volunteering to help them.

-Mail Settings: they had some email addresses bounce that are good email addresses. For example, when they send out emails, their emails bounce back. How can I fix this?

-Update CiviMail settings and website, so Unsubscribe and Opt-Out links are valid. Folks were able to use it in the first email they sent out, but now it doesn't work.

- MailChimp Extension: is there a MailChimp available to install with CiviCRM.

I did some searches on the forums to see if I can avoid asking you guys for help, but I couldn't find anything this specific. Again, I apologize, I know I'm in over my head, but I would like to learn this for my future.

Thanks!

EDIT: WordPress + Version 5.24.4

EDIT 2: This is the website: http://crm.allparksallianceforchange.org/wordpress

Comment: welcome - hard position to be in - good luck - and if you want you can also try your luck on chat.civicrm.org  - very few folk bite so you should get help. Worth mentioning your CMS and your Civi version.

Answer (score 2):

For your last question, a quick google of "civicrm mailchimp extension" gets

- https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-civicrm-integration (usage 795)
- https://civicrm.org/extensions/mailchimp-sync (usage 1)

Comment: Amazing Pete! Thank you SOOOO much for all this. I will check this out and I will report back my findings and hope everything is as easy as you make it :)

Also the version that I see installed in the WordPRess site is Version 5.24.4.

Thanks again! I really appreciate all of this!

Answer (score 1):

For the bounce issue. See if you can find out if SPF and DKIM have been set up. See if you can send an email direct to your own contact. Does it arrive? Check the headers for SPF and DKIM results.

Look in Mail Account settings (under Admin > CiviMail), and check the account for the Bounces. It should show you the login so you should be able to login to the account and see what is happening, or if the password is wrong then that could be the problem.

Check the Scheduled Job (under Admin > Settings) is running. View the log.
If you can add extensions, then add Job Log Viewer as it helps with generally seeing what else might be failing - https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Comment: One last thing, Pete, I'm sorry, I promise this should be the last thing, all these steps are done on the website, correct? Not in WordPress? Or am I wrong? 
Because they're telling me it's on their host and the version they have is only supposed to go through the dashboard on WordPress, that's their words. 
For example, I went to the dashboard, and I found CiviMail, but that takes me to a user guide.

Thanks again for your time, and I apologize for being such a pest!

Comment: best not to make such promises - and I can always ignore. It may help to familiarise yourself with https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ so you can see what is 'expected'

Comment: eg https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FmailSettings&reset=1 - so if that is the correct page on wp demo then use the path and try on yours

Comment: LOL! Too funny Pete, and I appreciate all of your help, I will use this link and figure stuff out with the info you've provided. Thank you so much!

Comment: ps - if you feel able to Accept one of the answers then it tidies the system up otherwise they show as having no accepted answers which isn't what we want.

Comment: Ok, that's great to know, Pete, thank you! You have no idea how much I appreciate your time and help! THANK YOU! This definitely helped me get my feet wet and it helped me understand what it is that I'm looking for and what to do.